# Loop Through a Directory and Append to Keyword Search CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have python code that will loop through a directory and find documents that contain certain keywords. When the keywords are found, the code will output the file name, the line number where the keyword is found and the text where the keyword/keywords is/are found:

```
csv1.csv, 7, Benefits, "between","hour","sport","chance","Benefits","cheese"
csv2.csv, 7, Benefits, "him","free","end","ants","hard","Benefits"
csv5.csv, 121, bird, "birds","select","whose","forth","paper","car"
```

When I save them to a CSV, only the last iteration is recorded in the  CSV file, in other words, if the df shows 3 documents with their keywords,  the saved CSV will contain only the 3rd document:

```
csv5.csv, 121, bird, "birds","select","whose","forth","paper","car"
```

I need a way to append the file so that all examples are shown in the saved CSV.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

words = ['Bonus Allocation', 'Benefits', 'bird']

for root, _, files in os.walk(r'E:\CSV_DOCS'):
    for path in filter(lambda p: p.endswith('.csv'), files):
        with open(os.path.join(root, path)) as f:
            for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
                for word in filter(lambda w: w in line, words):
                    print(f'{path}, {i+1}, {word}, {line.strip()}')
                    df= (f'{path}, {i+1}, {word}, {line.strip()}')
                    df.to_csv('E:\KeySearch.txt')
```

Comment: initialize an empty df at the beginning and then append new data within the for loop. Finally when the for loop is finished, do the `df.to_csv`

Comment: Thanks! I found that this solution solved my issue-- I updated the last line of code to this: 
         df.to_csv('E:\KeySearch.csv,mode='a',index=False,header=False)

Comment: I am now getting a "str' object has no attribute to.csv. This is weird because this worked recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it since I don't have the data nor do I have windows:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

words = ['Bonus Allocation', 'Benefits', 'bird']
data = []

for root, _, files in os.walk(r'E:\CSV_DOCS'):
    for path in filter(lambda p: p.endswith('.csv'), files):
        with open(os.path.join(root, path)) as f:
            for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
                for word in filter(lambda w: w in line, words):
                    print(f'{path}, {i+1}, {word}, {line.strip()}')
                    data.append({'path': path, 'line number': i+1, 'word': word, 'line': line.strip()})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('E:\KeySearch.csv')
```